# Using zlib to POST to Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, zlib

I found a similar question ([Error: incorrect header check at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:355:17) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190427/error-incorrect-header-check-at-zlib-handle-onerror-zlib-js35517-errno-3)) but that has not been answered.  I have not seen anything on Google forums either.

background:

- I ported zlib into my project
- I do not have a file system, so compress() is fed a report constructed as a JSON string.
- I know the JSON string is acceptable because if I POST it without compression everything works.
- I am using zlib in its simplest form (see [Using zlib deflateBound() dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559911/using-zlib-deflatebound-dynamically))
- If I do a self check (i.e. instead of sending the compressed message to the server, I feed it into deflate then compare the output to the original) everything look fine.

Symptoms

- The response I get to the POST is {"status":400,"error":"incorrect header check"}
- The server team is telling me that the error is thrown by gunzip so I am assuming the problem is with the gzip header, not the HTTP header.

  message: "{ Error: incorrect header check
      at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15)
    errno: -3,
    code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR',
    expose: true,
    statusCode: 400,
    status: 400 }"

Is there some magic setting in either end that is needed for this?  I have not found a Google document that says "use these settings for compression (not that zlib has a lot of settings)

Edit: everything I see mentions compressing *files*.  In fact the few samples I saw all show a filename if you look in the gzip header.  In my case, there is no file or filename, compress works on a string in memory and we send the resulting binary array directly.  I am nto sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: "Content-Encoding" was set to "gzip" but since I am sending a zlibstream rather than a .gz file, it should have been set to "deflate".

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding for details.